# Происхождение слова "вкалывать"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

В просторечии "вкалывать" — значит "тяжело и много работать". А вот интересно, откуда пошло это слово? Что вкалывать и в кого?)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Категорически не согласен, что слово появилось в середине XX века.

Вахмистр, старой службы, а не он генералам генерального штаба вкалывал? [М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон. Книга четвёртая (1928-1940)] 
(Нацкорпус).

Кирка - тоже от лукавого. Киркой не "вкалывают". Откалывают - я бы еще согласился. Т.е. у Солженицына - уже в переносном значении.

Мне почему-то кажется, что это именно от фельдшерского "ставить уколы". И изначально значило не просто тяжело работать, а обязательно - на кого (кому). Типа батрачить. Но не уверен.

Comment: > Вахмистр, старой службы, а не он генералам генерального штаба вкалывал? 
> [М. А. Шолохов. Тихий Дон. Книга четвёртая (1928-1940)]
> (Нацкорпус).

так тут же совсем другой смысл: он им вкалывал, тут действие обращено на субъект - им. Если бы было написано "А не он генералОм генерального штаба вкалывал?" - вот тогда бы это было подтверждением.

Comment: @DmitryOvchinnikov *так тут же совсем другой смысл:* - какой-такой "другой смысл" у слова "вкалывать"? Вашу логику про генералов - не понимаю абсолютно.

Comment: @DmitryOvchinnikov Вы бы не стеснялись излагать свои мысли подробно, додумывать за вас никто не будет.

Comment: "А кто у красных командирами? Буденный – офицер? Вахмистр, старой службы, а не он генералам генерального штаба вкалывал? А не от него топали офицерские полки?" - Вот полная цитата. Тут, по всей видимости, имеется в виду вкалывал шашкой. Как-то слабо сочетается с современной семантикой "работать"

Comment: @МаркИз "Полную цитату" я, разумеется, видел. А вот чтобы вахмистр вкалывал **шашкой** генералам генерального штаба - это что-то из области фантастики. Шашкой, кстати, хоть и считается она рубяще-колющим оружием, колоть не очень удобно. В этом смысле знающий человек использовал бы "рубить". Но это так, к слову. Основная непонятка в вашей версии: Что, куда и как мог ***генералам*** вкалывать ***вахмистр*** (прапорщик по-современному).  **На генералов** вкалывать ("пахать") я бы еще согласился. Так эту фразу у Ш. и понимаю.

Comment: Я понимаю эту фразу как вкалывал шашку в спину убегающим генералам генерального штаба. А вот работал на генералов как-то в контекст фразы плохо вписывается.

Comment: @МаркИз *вкалывал шашку в спину убегающим генералам* - за уши притянуто. Причем всё. И спины убегающих и шашка... Имхо. Видимо, это надо решать отдельным вопросом. Я не знаток Ш. да и не любитель его, но очень уж странный язык у белых офицеров...

Answer (score 5):

Можно предположить, что это проникновение в разговорную речь лагерного жаргона (от выражения вкалывать киркой?). Такое словосочетание встречается, например, у Александра Солженицына:

> И все те, кто воруют, киркой сами не
> вкалывают
>
> ("Один день Ивана Денисовича").

Время появление слова (примерно, середина ХХ века) и семантика (долго, нудно работать), говорят в пользу это версии.

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, слово "вкалывать" каким-то образом связано со словом "калымить" - работать, подрабатывать.

"Калымить", в свою очередь, произошло от "калым" - выкуп за невесту (не знаю из какого языка). То есть молодой человек, прежде чем жениться, должен был много трудиться, чтобы заработать на свадьбу.