# Почему "вкалывают"?

Tags: этимология

"Вкалывать" - много и трудно работать. А вот интересно, откуда пошло это слово? Что вкалывать и куда?)))
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение слова уже обсуждалось:
[Происхождение слова "вкалывать"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/21456/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)